# Where is submitChanges Method in Telerik.MVC.Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik-mvc

I am using the Telerik.MVC.Grid (version 2013.2.611) from Nuget

The following script

```
function mouseDown(e)
{
    var grid = document.getElementById("ColumnsEditor")
    grid.submitChanges();
}
```

throws error:
*Object doesn't support property or method 'submitChanges'*

Documentation indicates this is a valid method. If the method is invalid, is there an alternative method to call.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is getting the syntax correct. Once I got the grid properly typed, the submitChanges method shows in intellisense.

tGrid is the Type.

grdEditor is the grid name .

```
var grid = $('#grdEditor).data('tGrid');
grid.submitChanges();
```